# ggplot for loop problems

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I am trying to create ggplots based on a unique variable by using a for loop, and experiencing the following issues:
* This is a large data set (for my processing power, at least) of tree measurements, so I have subset them to make things a bit easier...
* I am happy to use baseplot if that is easier, they dont have to be pretty!

1. When I run the script on the smaller set, the plots are printed to pdf, but they repeat for the number of times that each unique/for variable occurs in the dataset (10-30 reps).
2. When I run the same script on a larger subset (only difference is the df name), i get the following:

geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
* I have tried aes(group = 1) and changing the variable types, with no luck...

Script and tibble below:

## Attempt a unique loop print to pdf

```
p <- list()
for(i in 1:length(Egra$Unique_Tree_Code)) {
  p[[i]] <- list()
  data <- subset(Egra, Unique_Tree_Code == Unique_Tree_Code[i])
  p[[i]][[1]] <- ggplot(data, aes(RelHt,RelDOB)) + geom_line() +
    ggtitle(data$Unique_Tree_Code) + xlim(0, 1) + ylim(0 , 1.25)
  }


library(gridExtra)

pdf("plots.pdf", onefile = TRUE)
for (i in seq(length(p))) {
  do.call("grid.arrange", p[[i]])  
}
dev.off()
```

## DF1

```
# A tibble: 851 x 4
    RelHt RelDOB RelDIB Unique_Tree_Code 
    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>            
 1 0.0170  1.06   0.944 100 B05a 11 1 233
 2 0.0341  1.04   0.871 100 B05a 11 1 233
 3 0.0568  1.03   0.863 100 B05a 11 1 233
 4 0.0739  0.996  0.854 100 B05a 11 1 233
 5 0.114   0.957  0.841 100 B05a 11 1 233
 6 0.170   0.944  0.820 100 B05a 11 1 233
 7 0.227   0.936  0.811 100 B05a 11 1 233
 8 0.284   0.897  0.803 100 B05a 11 1 233
 9 0.341   0.828  0.730 100 B05a 11 1 233
10 0.398   0.815  0.721 100 B05a 11 1 233
# ... with 841 more rows
```

## DF2

```
# A tibble: 1,772 x 4
    RelHt RelDOB RelDIB Unique_Tree_Code  
    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>             
 1 0.0113  1.05   1.04  100 A05e 9.8 1 248
 2 0.0226  1.04   0.940 100 A05e 9.8 1 248
 3 0.0376  1.00   0.915 100 A05e 9.8 1 248
 4 0.0489  1      0.899 100 A05e 9.8 1 248
 5 0.0752  0.960  0.863 100 A05e 9.8 1 248
 6 0.113   0.923  0.847 100 A05e 9.8 1 248
 7 0.150   0.911  0.843 100 A05e 9.8 1 248
 8 0.188   0.867  0.827 100 A05e 9.8 1 248
 9 0.226   0.863  0.806 100 A05e 9.8 1 248
10 0.263   0.859  0.798 100 A05e 9.8 1 248
# ... with 1,762 more rows
```

Comment: You should set a new variable `uTreeCode <- unique(Egra$Unique_Tree_Code)` which contains each value only once.  Then use this as the number of iterations of your loop, and in your subset statement.

Comment: Add `print(i)` at the start of your loop and figure out which subset of data causes the problem, and share that subset with us.

Comment: Making a list of plots is good. But you are making a list of lists, where each sub-list contains a single plot. Is there a reason for this? If not, (1) delete `p[[i]] <- list()`, (2) assign the plot `p[[i]] <- ggplot(...)`, not to `p[[i]][[1]]`, and (3) replace `do.call("grid.arrange", p[[i]]) ` with `grid.arrange(p[[i]])`, or probably simply `print(p[[i]])` will work.

Comment: @AndrewGustar Thanks, tried this but doesn't seem to work. Used the following:


uTreeCode <- unique(Pcar$Unique_Tree_Code)
p <- list()
for(i in 1:length(uTreeCode)) {
  
  data <- subset(Pcar, Unique_Tree_Code == uTreeCode)
  p[[i]] <- ggplot(data, aes(RelHt,RelDOB)) + geom_line() +
    ggtitle(data$Unique_Tree_Code) + xlim(0, 1) + ylim(0 , 1.25)
}

Still get the same result...

Comment: Hi @Gregor 

When I try this it doesn't print the plots. See script used:

for(i in 1:length(Pcar$Unique_Tree_Code)) {
  
  data <- subset(Pcar, Unique_Tree_Code == Unique_Tree_Code[i])
  p[[i]] <- ggplot(data, aes(RelHt,RelDOB)) + geom_line() +
    ggtitle(data$Unique_Tree_Code) + xlim(0, 1) + ylim(0 , 1.25)
}


library(gridExtra)

pdf("plots.pdf", onefile = TRUE)
for (i in seq(length(p))) {
  print(p[[i]])
}
dev.off()

Comment: @BenjaminvanHeerden You need `uTreeCode[i]` in the `subset` statement. I would also use it in the `ggtitle`.

Comment: @AndrewGustar this causes the dataframes from which it is plotting to only have one x-y pair. The dataframe must still be "big", i.e. contain all RelHt/x and RelDOB/y variables for that uTreeCode, but produce only one plot each.